Can an ISR "interrupt" an atomic operation?
Can an ISR "interrupt" an atomic operation?
Here's an example where this would matter:
I want to send data from an ISR to my main program.
To do so, I'm using the _Atomic BigStruct_t g_big global variable:
typedef struct {
   uint32_t array[10];
} BigStruct_t;

_Atomic BigStruct_t g_big;

volatile void ISR(uint32_t flags) {
    g_big = (BigStruct_t) { 
        .array[0] = flags
    };
}

int main(void) {
    while(1) {
        BigStruct_t big_copy = g_big;
        if (big_copy.array[0] == 1) {
            // do something
        }
    }
}

Because BigStruct_t is big, I assume the compiler will use a lock to guaranty my copies are atomic. If the program starts executing line  BigStruct_t big_copy = g_big and an interrupt occurs, what happens? Is the CPU smart enough to wait for the atomic operation to ends before executing the ISR?
I tried looking in Dr. Yifeng Zhu - embedded Systems with ARM Cortex-M Microcontrollers in Assembly Language and C, but I didn't find what I was looking for.
EDIT:
My applogies if I was not clear. I don't want a specific answer for a specific IC. I want a mental model to solve the problem myself.
I assume the way ISRs and atomic instructions interacts is define by the processor I'm using. That said, I didn't find information about this topic when I looked for ARM cortex-m4 or RISCV32.
Also, I don't know if it will be affected by the C memory model / optimization (therefore my choice of compiler) or the atomic library implementation (therefore my choice of libc).

It depends which compiler and which platform you mean. We can't possibly know if your compiler for your platform implements it or not.

updated the question!

There is no generic answer. Either the compiler and libraries work with or without interrupts, or it may be selectable, or you can implement the lock functions yourself like you would for an OS threads so you can implement them to disable interrupts too. It's all about the implementarion. And not exactly an EE question but software engineering question about compilers.

The best mental model is "if an interrupt happens during an atomic operation, it is restarted." This is trivial for small types -- you basically say "if anyone else modified that value since I've read it, do not perform my update, and flag an error." Atomic operations on larger types emulate this behaviour,

The problem is, you're asking as if this is a general thing, but this is a non-standard feature of a variant compiler, and it seems no one offhand has recognized the exact toolchain. You must work backwards, starting with where you saw this combination in the first place (what toolchain, for what platform). Then read the documentation to understand how those features work, and maybe read around to see the history of that toolchain and/or platform. Language features evolve over time, sometimes adopting new desirable features, others persisting in their own way.

Reading the GCC manual provides some parallel insight: they support a vast array of platforms, with as much in common (and supporting standard C) as possible, and then there are platform-specific quirks, mostly in #pragmas and attributes, but also instruction support, some language keywords, and particularly in backend features like integrating ASM (and what ASM syntax is used), the ABI, memory model, various flags controlling output generation, etc. etc. Platforms with concurrency support might indeed have a _Atomic, but it will be just that, platform-specific.

The reason GCC doesn't unify language syntax (at least for backend matter like mentioned) is because it would break massive swaths of existing codebase, and no one's going to choose a compiler that forces them to port over and refactor their entire codebase. Rather, traditions are maintained, in such pockets as they are acceptable, while standard language is used elsewhere. Now consider a platform-specific compiler: they may have completely independent heritage, support a subset of standard C, use proprietary syntax and keywords, etc.

Reading a few online references regarding _atomic, it would seem that the semantics only guarantee that updates to the object are atomic — they say nothing about reads of the object being atomic. So on that basis, I would have to say yes, the copy operation in your example can be interrupted.
But in general, and especially in real-time embedded systems (which I'm assuming is why this question appears here), it is usually poor practice to require atomic updates to large structures. It is better to use arrays of smaller structures, with atomically-updated flags and other status variables to control how they are shared among multiple threads (including ISRs). This is why an RTOS (Real-Time Operating System) usually provides primitives like FIFOs and semaphores, which do exactly that. And you can do the same thing yourself if you're programming at the bare-metal level.

I also thought the atomic operations are between threads. Which would mean the compiler and the underlying libc implementation could only work between threads of some sort - it might not mean the operation is atomic with regards to interrupts.

This is much simpler. When using _Atomic with complex types, all you can do in a well-defined manner is replace the whole thing: Accessing a member of an atomic struct/union is undefined behavior..

As noted in a comment:

It depends which compiler and which platform you mean. We can't possibly know if your compiler for your platform implements it or not. - Justme

Out of curiosity I tried building the example program from the question using   gcc (GCC) 10.3.1 20210520 (for GNAT Community 2021 20210519) for the Linux x86-64 platform.
The C source file compiled without error, but the linker reported errors about unresolved references to __atomic_store and __atomic_load:
[ 98%] Linking C executable test_atomic_struct
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/test_atomic_struct.dir/test_atomic_struct.c.o: in function `ISR':
/home/mr_halfword/ibv_message_passing/ibv_message_passing_c_project/source/atomic_struct/test_atomic_struct.c:18:(.text+0x50): undefined reference to `__atomic_store'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/test_atomic_struct.dir/test_atomic_struct.c.o: in function `main':
/home/mr_halfword/ibv_message_passing/ibv_message_passing_c_project/source/atomic_struct/test_atomic_struct.c:25:(.text+0x75): undefined reference to `__atomic_load'

The linker errors went away when the length of the array in BigStruct_t was reduced from 10 (total structure size 320 bits) to 2 (total structure size 64 bits).
I have previously used the same compiler on code which the __atomic_store_n and __atomic_load_n built-ins to operate lock-free on data types which are either 8 or 32-bits.
The conclusion is that GCC on a x86-64 platform:

Can perform lock-less atomic operations, using CPU instructions, for data types up to 64-bits.
For data types more than 64-bits the compiler inserts calls to __atomic_store and __atomic_load_n run time functions to handle the atomic operations.

I.e. as expected the answer depends upon the combination of compiler, CPU and runtime environment.

Out of curiosity, why test with x86-64? Surely the context of question isn't making linux programs reacting to interrupts. If it is, it would be off-topic.

Using x86-64 was only because that was the IDE I had open - my answer is really a hint to investigate how the unspecified platform in the question handles use of _Atomic.

If the question gets re-opened with details of the platform in use, will attempt to update this answer from being generic to specific.

You need to link with libatomic -- technically always, but if all uses are inlined, you can often get away with forgetting to link the library.
